# Dilemma evaluating integral after sinusoidal substitution

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

To solve the definite integral

$$ I = \int_{-a}^{a} \frac{dx}{\pi \sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$$

I used the substitution $x = a \sin \theta$ and tried to solve the integral without its interval definition, which yields

$$ I = \frac{\theta}{\pi} $$

Now according to what I have been taught, from this point on I can do either of two things:

- write the result in terms of $x$ and evaluate with the initial limits; or
- transform $x$'s limits into limits for $\theta$ and evaluate.

Selecting the first option listed, the result of the evaluation is 1, but selecting the second option I get as result
$$ x = a \Rightarrow \theta = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi n$$
$$x=-a\Rightarrow \theta = \frac{3 \pi}{2} + 2 \pi k$$
$$ I = \frac{\theta}{\pi} = \left(\frac{1}{2} + 2n\right) - \left(\frac{3}{2} + 2k \right) = 2(n-k)-1$$

(where $n$ and $k$ are integers.) Why would $n-k=1$ so this result would also be correct?

Comment: Substitution is only allowed for bijections. You should double-check your bounds on $\theta$ to trace $[-a,a]$ exactly once. You should therefor pick $\theta \in [-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ and see $n=0, k=-1$.

Comment: Do you mean that $\theta$ has to cross its bounds in the same order $x$ does? In this case, since $x$ is first $-a$, $\theta$ can't first be $\pi/2$; did I get it right?

Comment: Not necessarily, but if you allow more than a range of $[a, a+\pi]$ where $a = 2\pi k-\frac{pi}{2}$, you won't have a bijection anymore. The order (i.e. from $a$ to $-a$ or reversed) doesn't matter and will be annulled by the derivative (it will change signs).

Comment: So since it takes $\pi$ for sine to go from $u$ to $-u$ once (where $|u|=1$), my $\theta$ range has to be $\pi$ long? I can get my mind around that, but I don't get why my range needs to be of the form $[a, a+\pi$] if order doesn't matter. (Perhaps it would help if I let you know I am considering a bijection only within $\theta$'s limits, I don't know if this is wrong.)

Comment: I guess I now understand your bijection rule,. I read up on a PDF taken from one of Steward's Calculus books on trigonometric substitutions where it says that the intervals of the original variable of integration and that of the substitution must be able to be converted from one to the other and back. Is that it?

Comment: Wolter, yes that's exactly what formally is a bijection.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! (I am sorry I didn't know better the definition of bijection heheh.) PS: You should make that an answer and I'll mark your answer as the solution :)

Comment: Wolter, I did that now; is that up to your expectations or do you need anything added?

Comment: Thank you! I think it would be good if you constrained $k$ according to the bijection limitations

Comment: $k\in\mathbb Z$ is the full constraint ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $a\gt0$, here is the result of your substitution
$$
\begin{align}
I
&=\int_{-a}^a\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\pi\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\\
&=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{a\cos(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta}{\pi a\cos(\theta)}\\
&=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\pi}\\
\end{align}
$$
You have to change the limits to match the change of variable. That is, as $x$ varies from $-a$ to $a$, $\theta$ varies from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$. Note that $\cos(\theta)$ is positive over this range, so $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}=a\cos(\theta)$.

---

**Changing direction of the parameterization**
It is possible to use the interval $[\pi/2,3\pi/2]$, as long as you match things up. We then use $x=-a\sin(\theta)$ and $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}=-a\cos(\theta)$
$$
\begin{align}
I
&=\int_{-a}^a\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\pi\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\\
&=\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}\frac{-a\cos(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta}{-\pi a\cos(\theta)}\\
&=\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\pi}\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I didn't understand why $\cos{\theta}$ being possitive is important, can you elaborate?

Comment: $\cos(\theta) \neq 0$ a.e. is important.

Comment: @WolterHellmund: $\cos(\theta)\gt0$ is important since $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\gt0$. If $\cos{\theta}$ were negative, then $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ would be $-a\cos{\theta}$.

Comment: So could this be another way of picking my $\theta$ interval? (Making sure there are no non-real possible evaluations throughout the integration steps.)

Comment: @WolterHellmund: You can pick any interval for $\theta$ for which $a\sin(\theta)$ varies from $-a$ to $a$.

Comment: Yeah I thought I understood that, but @AlexR says order (in which $a$ and $-a$ are reached by $a \sin \theta$) is not relevant. If order isn't relevant then I don't get why is $[\pi/2, 3\pi/2]$ a wrong interval for $\theta$, it reaches $a$ first and $-a$ second.

Comment: @WolterHellmund: I have added a section to my answer discussing the use of $[\pi/2,3\pi/2]$.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating even further, could I say that your last edit confirms that your point is that order does matter?

Comment: @WolterHellmund: Well, if by order you mean that
$\int_{-a}^a\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\pi\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$ is different than $\int_a^{-a}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\pi\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$, then yes, order does matter as they are negatives of each other.

Comment: Well of course, but I am talking about the order in which $a$ and $-a$ are reached by $x$ given $\theta$'s interval and $x$'s definition in terms of $\theta$. (See 6th comment.)

Comment: @WolterHellmund: However, you can use the substitution $y=-x$ to get
$$
\int_{-a}^a\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\pi\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}=\int_a^{-a}\frac{-\mathrm{d}y}{\pi\sqrt{a^2-y^2}}
$$
and in this case the order of the limits is reversed, which is analogous to the case you describe.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is, you have to exactly specify the bijection (one-to-one and onto) used for the substitution.

$$u(\theta) = a \sin(\theta)$$
maps bijective to $[-a,a]$ for several choices of ${\rm Dom}_u$. The most straight-forward of these is
$$u: \left [-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right ] \to [-a,a]$$
But the only limitations on the domain are

1. $\left.\sin\right|_D$ must be a bijection
2. If $D = [d_0, d_1]$ then $\sin(d_0) \in \{-1,1\} \ni \sin(d_1) \neq \sin(d_0)$ so that the endpoints $u(d_0), u(d_1) \in \{-a,a\}$ and by intermediate value theorem $u(D) = [-a,a]$ since $\sin(D) = [-1,1]$

So to find the range of theta start with a maximum at $\sin(d_0)$, i.e.
$$\cos(d_0) = 0 \Leftrightarrow d_0 = \frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi, \qquad k\in \mathbb{Z}$$
and take an interval of length $\pi$, so that $\sin(d_1) = \sin(d_0 + \pi) = -\sin(d_0)$. You get
$$D = [\frac{\pi}{2} + k\pi, \frac{\pi}{2} + (k+1) \pi]$$
In your above notation $"n-k" = (k+1)-k = 1$ so your two solutions are the same (correct).

Comment: but k=0 yields $D = [\pi/2, 3\pi/2]$ and that's wrong, isn't it?

Comment: Nope, that's perfectly fine, but the integral will transform to
$$\int_{\frac{3\pi}{2}}^\frac{\pi}{2} \ldots$$
Which is where the sign reveses to the correct result ;-)